# How are uniqueidentifiers calculated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, guid, uniqueidentifier

I was curious as to how SQL Server calculates uniqueidentifiers. I understand that uniqueidentifiers, are GUIDs but are these calculated based on system time?  Or are they calculated based on the name of job/script that has called the NEWID() function. I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) but i found this reference to be unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are generating them from `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` (the [last one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379322%28VS.85%29.aspx) uses an algorithm involving the mac address the first one [doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205%28VS.85%29.aspx))

Comment: How could the GUID change? Is it possible that jobs that run on SQL Server be assigned a new GUID if the server were to be reset?

Comment: @jgroat - No . That should remain permanent as far as I know. I assume this is related to your question yesterday? Maybe if you are seeing odd behaviour with the SQL Server jobs table post a new question describing the odd behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: I'm actually trying to store data from some system tables and if the GUID changes on system restart I have to find a new way to uniquely identify each job.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

I find the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) entry quite informative.

Comment: I guess, when in doubt, wikipedia. Thanks